# Performance: XPATH vs ApplyTemplates

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I need to convert an xml to flat file, I am wondering if writing tempate sections for each group of children will be performant against writing long xpath expressions in select, or does it not matter after the transformer is compiled (I use java xml libs).
For example

```
<xsl:template match="country">   
 Country=<xsl:value-of select="name">
  ...   
 <xsl:apply-template select="movie"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
 MovieName=<xsl:value-of select="name">
 Year=<xsl:value-of select="year">
</xsl:template>
```

Vs

```
<xsl:template match="country">   
 Country=<xsl:value-of select="name">
 ...
 MovieName=<xsl:value-of select="movie/name">
 Year=<xsl:value-of select="movie/year">
</xsl:template>
```

The source is not too big but it has few child blocks like movie and upto three deep levels.

Comment: In XSLT, performance is seldom the top priority. Still, the most reliable way to find out is to actually test this. Why don't you go ahead and measure the time or resources?

Comment: sure, will test if I dont get any points here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is performance more important to you than writing simple correct robust and maintainable code? If not, forget it.
2. Performance depends on the XSLT processor you are using. For example Saxon and XSLTC are both considerably faster than the default JDK processor (interpretive Xalan). And the relative performance of different ways of writing your code also depends on which processor you are using; one way of writing it might be faster with Xalan, a different way with Saxon.
3. Performance also depends on how you run the processor; for example Saxon is ten times faster with its own native tree model than when run against a DOM.
4. Answers to questions such as "which is faster" are unreliable. The reliable way to get the answer to such a question is to make careful measurements. ("Careful" means, for example, taking care to ensure that you are discounting the effect of Java warm-up time, unless Java warm-up time is part of your production workload.)